# NotificationCompat and API checks

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-support-library

Does one need to perform an API check if say we use setGroupAlertBehavior from NotificationCompat on Android OS API 19-25?

Comment: your IDE will warn you

Comment: Our tests indicate no warning from IDE and no crash when running on OS 4.4.x, 6.x and 7.x.

Comment: @Android You should still do, because it depends on the manufacturer too.

Answer (score 1):

[**setGroupAlertBehavior**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setGroupAlertBehavior(int)) is used to change the notification grouping behavior.

The feature of notification groups is only available on **Android 7.0 (API level 24) and above** which is not backward compatible so yes you need to put an API level check before using it

[From Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group.html#set_a_group_summary)

> `On Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher, the system automatically
>   builds a summary for your group using snippets of text from each
>   notification`. The user can expand this notification to see each
>   separate notification, as shown in figure 1. `To support older
>   versions, which cannot show a nested group of notifications, you must
>   create an extra notification that acts as the summary`. This appears as
>   the only notification and the system hides all the others. So this
>   summary should include a snippet from all the other notifications,
>   which the user can tap to open your app.

**so to barely imitate the behavior of group notifications on older devices , you need to have separate coding behavior hence you need API level check because for older devices**.

> Our tests indicate no warning from IDE and no crash when running on OS
>   4.4.x, 6.x and 7.x. Odd.

`NotificationCompat` use different method to build the notification for different platform so the `int` parameter passed to `setGroupAltertBehavior` will never be used while creating notifications for api below `20` so yes it is safe to use it on API below `20`

See when `setGroupAltertBehavior` is called

```
 public Builder setGroupAlertBehavior(int groupAlertBehavior) {
        mGroupAlertBehavior = groupAlertBehavior;
        return this;
    }
```

but `mGroupAlertBehavior` will never be used on API 19 and below as

```
 @RequiresApi(19)
    static class NotificationCompatApi19Impl extends NotificationCompatApi16Impl {
        @Override
        public Notification build(Builder b, BuilderExtender extender) {
            NotificationCompatKitKat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompatKitKat.Builder(
                    b.mContext, b.mNotification, b.resolveTitle(), b.resolveText(), b.mContentInfo,
                    b.mTickerView, b.mNumber, b.mContentIntent, b.mFullScreenIntent, b.mLargeIcon,
                    b.mProgressMax, b.mProgress, b.mProgressIndeterminate, b.mShowWhen,
                    b.mUseChronometer, b.mPriority, b.mSubText, b.mLocalOnly,
                    b.mPeople, b.mExtras, b.mGroupKey, b.mGroupSummary, b.mSortKey,
                    b.mContentView, b.mBigContentView);
            addActionsToBuilder(builder, b.mActions);
            addStyleToBuilderJellybean(builder, b.mStyle);
            return extender.build(b, builder);
        }


    @RequiresApi(20)
    static class NotificationCompatApi20Impl extends NotificationCompatApi19Impl {
        @Override
        public Notification build(Builder b, BuilderExtender extender) {
            NotificationCompatApi20.Builder builder = new NotificationCompatApi20.Builder(
                    b.mContext, b.mNotification, b.resolveTitle(), b.resolveText(), b.mContentInfo,
                    b.mTickerView, b.mNumber, b.mContentIntent, b.mFullScreenIntent, b.mLargeIcon,
                    b.mProgressMax, b.mProgress, b.mProgressIndeterminate, b.mShowWhen,
                    b.mUseChronometer, b.mPriority, b.mSubText, b.mLocalOnly, b.mPeople, b.mExtras,
                    b.mGroupKey, b.mGroupSummary, b.mSortKey, b.mContentView, b.mBigContentView,
                    b.mGroupAlertBehavior);
 // used on API 20+. ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ but not below
            addActionsToBuilder(builder, b.mActions);
            addStyleToBuilderJellybean(builder, b.mStyle);
            Notification notification = extender.build(b, builder);
            if (b.mStyle != null) {
                b.mStyle.addCompatExtras(getExtras(notification));
            }
            return notification;
        }
```

Comment: Our tests indicate no warning from IDE and no crash when running on OS 4.4.x, 6.x and 7.x. Odd.

Comment: it might possible, maybe due to manufacturer or some optimizations (though you might find something in logcat) but try the updated answer

Comment: I'm not buying the manufacturer angle. Remember this is NotifcationCompat which is part of the support library.

Comment: I am not selling it either and I remember but have you even looked at the updated answer, there is no support of notification group on old versions so there is different approach for both the platforms

Comment: Sure there's no support of notification group on old versions but the call does not crash hence is the support library handling this gracefully?

Comment: I has no effect on api 19 and below, hence no crash but as suggested, you can use different approaches to replicate the behaviour into one notification as summary on API 19 and below